# Error Using a Makefile For a Linux Shell Written in C

Tags: c, linux, unix, makefile

I created a Linux shell for one of my classes written in C. The shell works perfectly running such commands as ls, pwd, ps, top, cd, etc.

However, using a MakeFile (because that is part of the submission process), when the you use the command "make test" in Terminal I get the error `tcsetpgrp: Inappropriate ioctl for device"`amongst all of the correct output of my program. Within the Makefile I have `test: test.txt | .project4.c` with test.txt being the commands, ls, pwd, ps, top, cd separated by newlines instead of commas. What is this error and how do I get rid of it?

Here is my makefile:

```
PAWPRINT=myname

project4:

clean:
    rm -f *.o

nuke:
    rm -f *.o project4 *.gz

test: project4
    cat test.txt | ./project4   

submit.sh:
    wget -O submit.sh http://somewebsite.com/submit.sh
    chmod +x submit.sh

project4.tar.gz: project4.c test.txt Makefile
    mkdir -p dist
    cp $^ dist
    tar -cvzf $@ dist

 submit: submit.sh project4.tar.gz
    PAWPRINT=$(PAWPRINT) sh submit.sh project4.tar.gz
```

Here is my test.txt file:

```
sleep 1000 &
jobs
pwd
ls
echo hello > a.txt
echo world > b.txt
cat a.txt b.txt > c.txt
cat c.txt
```

My program can run these commands individually outside of the makefile. I designed the program to handles these commands because that is what the assignment was for.

Comment: Please post the whole Makefile.

Comment: Putting `cd` commands into a Makefile recipe sounds suspicious, since they will be ineffective. Putting `top` into a Makefile recipe sounds even more suspicious. As for separating commands with commas? No shell-like language I know does this. So as user1202136 said, please post your Makefile.

Comment: Useless Use of Cat inside Makefile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you're saying, as make sense, that the tcsetpgrp is coming from your program output right? Well this has mothing to do with your MakeFile, but as a result of running the program inside the submission process. Your program is attempting to become a process group and thus is trying to tell its controlling terminal that it's the foreground process. But there is no terminal because you're inside the submission process, so tcsetpgrp() complains (man tcsetpgrp(3) for more information). Generally this is harmless, though annoying.

Comment: I attached the requested files.

Comment: The problem with this is that this is for an assignment and the "error messages" are making me lose points on the assignment if I don't figure out a way to fix it. Any ideas?

Comment: @Kaz I thought the same thing, but without the preceding cat, I get the error message `myshell# /bin/sh: test.txt: command not found` since my shell doesn't recognize test.txt as a command.